# Changing -webkit-transform using jQuery not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have made a simple jQuery script to create a line and make it move along with cursor. [Find its fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/sgsvenkatesh/hepbob75/9/)

This is how I am assigning the slope

```js
$("#line").css({
    "width": + width +"px", 
    "height": "4px", 
    "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + slope + "deg)", 
    "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + slope + "deg)"
});
```

The line is flickering in Chrome and not working in Firefox. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although as pointed out it is advisable to use `transform` without vendor prefixes (because jQuery *automagically* adds vendor prefixes for you), that is not the source of the problem. I realized that using `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY` is giving conflicting values that constantly flips between positive and negative values upon mousemove, causing the slope calculation to be borked (thus flickering).

I have created a [fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/hepbob75/14/) to demonstrate how `offsetX/Y` and `clientX/Y` measurements are different, and why using the latter is preferable:

Instead, use the `.clientX` and `.clientY` objects instead:

```
$(document).bind("mousemove", function(event) {
    if (getClickStarted){

        if (event && event.preventDefault){
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        // Use clientX/Y instead of offsetX/Y
        curX = event.clientX;
        curY = event.clientY;

        var width = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(curX - centerX, 2) + Math.pow(curY - centerY, 2));
        var slope = Math.atan2(curY - centerY, curX - centerX)*180/Math.PI;

        // Use unprefixed transform
        $("#line").css({
            "width": + width +"px",
            "height": "4px",
            "transform": "rotate(" + slope + "deg)"
        });
    }
});
```

See fixed fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/hepbob75/12/

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the standard `transform`:

```
$("#line").css({
   "width": + width +"px", 
   "height": "4px", 
   "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + slope + "deg)", 
   "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + slope + "deg)",
   "transform": "rotate(" + slope + "deg)"//make sure works in newer browsers
});
```

By the way this should also work:

```
$("#line").css({
  "width": + width +"px", 
  "height": "4px", 
  "transform": "rotate(" + slope + "deg)"// jQuery adds vendor prefixes.
});
```

Comment: [There is no need for vendor prefixes other than `-webkit-` (and `-ms-` if IE9 has to be supported)](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform).

Comment: Nope. This did not solve the problem. Edited fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sgsvenkatesh/hepbob75/13/